# Don't know how to make this symbol!

Tags: symbols

for school we need to make this kind of operation:

[image: The symbol]

Can somebody tell me how to make this big brackets and write the number inside in this way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please, are you typesetting a 2-dimensional vector, a binomial coefficient, or something else?

Comment: Is for a 2-dimensional vector! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `$\binom{-3}{1}$` from `\usepackage{amsmath}`, if you work in LaTeX. However, if you wanna make a vector instead, it's `\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix}` from the same package.

Comment: The output will be as desired, but I think `\binom{}{}` should not abused for something looking like a vector ;-) (I don't think that the OP meant the generalization of the binomial coefficients to real numbers)

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for!